# Dagger-gRPC server annotation processor

Tags: java, grpc, dagger-2, dagger, grpc-java

I'm trying to use Dagger in a java gRPC service project. I've been following the official documentation of Dagger for creating gRPC servers available here: [gRPC servers with Dagger](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/grpc-servers.html).
Upon building, Dagger should automatically create auto generated classes from the used annotation (@GrpcService). Unfortunately, I can't get the program to auto generate the needed classes when I compile.

I'm using "dagger-grpc-server" maven dependency version 2.28.1 and gRPC version 1.30.2. Also, I tried adding "dagger-grpc-server-processor" version 2.28.1 to the annotationProcessorPaths once, and I tried adding "dagger-grpc-server-annotations" version 2.28.1 to the annotationProcessorPaths, but neither of them worked.

The goal is to get dagger to automatically create the generated files during compilation. Which plugins am I missing?

Reference to the open issue on Dagger project: [Issue 2157](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2157)

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and give us that code so we can examine it.

Comment: (FWIW, I think it's a fine question @MostafaAmer-2.)